# Importing a .x file to 3D Studio Max?

Tags: 3d, directx, models

I've been googling this for a while and haven't been able to find anything (blenders importer does not work). How can I import a .x file to 3D Studio Max? There are heaps of resources in converting formats readable by Max to .x but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download [Milkshape](http://chumbalum.swissquake.ch), you can import the DirectX file and export it as a Collada, Fbx, or Obj, which can be imported into 3DS Max.

Comment: It doesn't have an option to import .x files...

Comment: It should be on the top menu bar, under Tools -> DirectX Mesh Tools... -> Import .x file